# error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'date'). ExpenseDate.js line 4

Tags: reactjs

I am taking a REACT course on Udemy and have followed along throughout all the instruction and have no idea why my app isn't rendering any ideas? [Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSsjZ.png)

Comment: Change `export` statement inside *ExpenseDate* component from `ExpenseDate()` to `ExpenseDate`. You need to use component references inside *JSX* so that *babel* can parse it correctly.

Comment: And please read [Why should I not upload any images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please post a console.log(props) in both components along with some code.